# How do I correctly specify name and attributes when creating users in AD

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to PowerShell and was hoping someone could help me understand where I'm going wrong with a script I am wanting to create.

The script's purpose is to take a First and Last name as mandatory values and store then in $FirstNames and $LastNames. It is then to add them together and create $Samaccountname. 
This is then fed to a ForEach-Object loop to create a user account per object provided to $Samaccountname with an array providing extra attributes to -otherattributes.

Please see below my code:

```
  Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string[]]$FirstNames
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string[]]$LastNames
    )

    #This will create new users with pre-set attributes based on an array.

    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $Samaccountnames = $FirstNames+$LastNames

    $OtherAttributes = @{
    City="Sunderland"
    Department="IT"
    Title='1st Line Analyst'
    #This is the 'Office' attribute
    office='Sunderland IT Building'
    Path='OU=Sunderland,OU=North East,OU=Lab Users,DC=*******,DC=***'
    }

    foreach($Samaccountname in $Samaccountnames)
    {
    New-ADUser -name $Samaccountname @OtherAttributes
    }
```

This created users with Samaccount names coming from $firstnames. It also did not apply a surname attribute.

Many thanks

Comment: You might want to provide examples of the data being fed into your script; the format of the names in particular

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're taking two arrays and trying to add them to each other.  It would make *more* sense to just take what you want: `SamAccountName`.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]
    $SamAccountName
)
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$attributes = @{
    'City'       = 'Sunderland'
    'Department' = 'IT'
    'Title'      = '1st Line Analyst'
    'Office'     = 'Sunderland IT Building'
    'Path'       = 'OU=Sunderland,OU=North East,OU=Lab Users,DC=*,DC=*'
}

foreach ($Name in $SamAccountName) {
    New-ADUser -Name $Name @attributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both name and surname are mandatory - the quantity of them will be the same.
I would recommend you to create a new samaccountname for each name in $FirstNames and add it to an array of samaccountnames.

```
Param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string[]]$FirstNames
,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string[]]$LastNames
)

#This will create new users with pre-set attributes based on an array.

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Samaccountnames = @() #define $samaccountnames as an array

#for each name in $firstnames we create new samaccountname and add it to samaccountnames array
foreach ($item in (0..$Firstnames.count)) #
    {
$samaccountnames += $firstnames[$item]+$lastnames[$item] 
    }

$attributes = @{
'City'       = 'Sunderland'
'Department' = 'IT'
'Title'      = '1st Line Analyst'
'Office'     = 'Sunderland IT Building'
'Path'       = 'OU=Sunderland,OU=North East,OU=Lab Users,DC=*,DC=*'}

foreach($Samaccountname in $Samaccountnames)
{
New-ADUser -name $Samaccountname @OtherAttributes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you possibly clarify what the following does step by step?

foreach ($item in (0..$Firstnames.count)) #
    {
$samaccountnames += $firstnames[$item]+$lastnames[$item] 
    }

Comment: $Firstnames is an array of names, which means it may contain several values for example (Steve,John). Same story about $Lastnames (Smith, Johnson for example)
`$firstnames.count` counts the amount of names(in our case 2 - Steve and John)
 `foreach ($item in (0..$Firstnames.count))` $item in this case represents name's index(position in other words) in the array $Firstnames. Array's count always starts from 0.
The code in the loop says "take the first item(Steve) in the $firstnames and add to it the first item (Smith) in the $lastnames array. Save it as an item in the array $samaccountnames"

Comment: Sorry I reached character limit in the comment.

And the loop keeps creating new $samaccountnames items for each name in the `$Firstnames`, so that next item in `$Firstnames` will be John and `Johnson` in the `$Lastnames`